# Plot grafico barras agrupadas associado a pontos ligados por linhas

Tags: r, ggplot2

Não estou conseguindo realizar o agrupamento das barras do gráfico abaixo mesmo utilizando o argumento `position = "dodge"` no `geom_bar`.

Encontrei pesquisas apenas com barras individuais, estou com dificuldade de criar esse gráfico com pontos+linhas quando as barras estão agrupadas.

Segue o comando que estou utilizando e um exemplo de como gostaria de deixar o gráfico.

```
dt <- data.frame(periodo = c ("junho", "julho", "agosto"), 
                 peso = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3),  
                 atr = c(0.95, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.8)) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = dt$periodo, y = dt$peso), 
    stat = "identity", 
    fill = "lightblue", 
    position= "dodge", 
    width = 0.8) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = dt$periodo, y = dt$atr),
    size = 1, color = "blue") + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = dt$periodo, y = dt$atr),
    size = 1, color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Período") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Peso", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5, name = "ATR", 
                        labels = function(b) {paste0(round(b*100, 0), "%")})) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", 
    title = "Dry - off", 
    subtitle = "Comparativo - Peso x ATR")
```

[[image: Gráfico desejado1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ter as barras agrupadas, precisa de uma variável que indique para o `ggplot` qual linha pertence a qual grupo:

```
library(ggplot2)

dt$grupo <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)

# Ordena os níveis da variável período para serem plotados na ordem correta
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("junho", "julho", "agosto"))

ggplot(dt, aes(periodo, peso, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Removi as personalizações para ressaltar as partes relevantes do código. Algumas observações:

- `ggplot` trabalha internamente com `with`: indique o objeto com os dados e pode passar os nomes das variáveis diretamente.
- elementos da estética que são usados para várias geometrias podem ser indicados na `aes` global
- `geom_col` é a versão da `gem_bar` que usa `stat = "identity"` por padrão.

Quanto às linhas/pontos, o gráfico que postou de exemplo possui uma representação inadequada dos dados: mostra os valores de todos os grupos como uma única sequência. Para fazer uma representação mais adequada, pode separar por grupo, usando `position_nudge` para ajustar a posição com as barras:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(as.integer(periodo), atr, color = grupo)) + # para linhas, a variável do eixo X precisa ser contínua
  geom_col(aes(periodo, peso, fill = grupo, color = NULL),
    position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(
    data = subset(dt, grupo == "A"),
    position = position_nudge(x = -.25)) +
  geom_point(
    data = subset(dt, grupo == "A"),
    position = position_nudge(x = -.25)) +
  geom_line(
    data = subset(dt, grupo == "B"),
    position = position_nudge(x = .25)) +
  geom_point(
    data = subset(dt, grupo == "B"),
    position = position_nudge(x = .25)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkblue"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]